# parsing http api response with php

Tags: php

I am using domain reseller API, which delivers response in html.
But, it is not formatted at all. I get something like this, in the form of one string:

```
domain.com: error: 102 your credentals are wrong
```

or

```
other-domain.net: OK: 202 domain is available
```

I am only interested in status code, by which I can send custom message to client. How would I parse that code from this string ?
Note that response can vary in length. I am thinking to use reg exp ?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried versions with reg exp, and with native PHP string manipulation. I am concerned by change in the length of response.

Comment: I see, but where is your code? ;-) That was the whole intention of my first question…

Answer (score 1):

This code might works

```
$string='other-domain.net: OK: 202 domain is available';
$array = explode(' ', $string);
echo $array[2]; // 202
```

Answer (score 1):

The statuscode apparently is always prefixed by colon and a white space

```
$statusText = 'other-domain.net: OK: 202 domain is available';

$status = preg_replace( '/.*: (\d+).+/', '$1', $statusText );
```